# lightning-spinner does not show up when a js function is working

Tags: lightning-web-components, asynchronous, js, promises, spinner

Here is my code

```
// Need to use the result from Promise but it is coming false
const validateCompleted = await this.validateData(data);
if(validateCompleted){
    ...
}

// When validating data, I want a spinner to show up
validateData(data){
    this.loading = true;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let ind=0;
        while(ind<data.length){
          let row=this.validateAndUpdate(data[ind]);
          if(row.rowErrorMessage){
            this.isDataValid=false;
          }
          ind++;
        }
        if(!this.isDataValid){
          this.failedRecords=data;
        }
        resolve(true);
      }, 0);
    })
    .then(
      () => this.loading = false
    );
  }

// Here is the html part for the spinner
...
<template if:true={loading}>
      <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"> 
      </lightning-spinner>
</template>
...
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: I've updated the post. But I think the problem is the response from validateData function. It should come true to be able to proceed with the rest of the process.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the solution for my scenario.

```
async validateData2(data) {
    this.loading = true;
    // Validation row by row
    try {
        // Got rid of the while loop
        for(let ind = 0; ind < data.length; ind++){
          // Made the validateAndUpdate method async also
          let row = await this.validateAndUpdate(data[ind]);
          if(row.rowErrorMessage){
            this.isDataValid = false;
          }
        }

        if (!this.isDataValid) {
            this.failedRecords = data;
        }
        // Resolve with true if validation is completed
        return true; 
    } 
    finally {
        // Ensure spinner is turned off
        this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```